# How to fill dictionary from wcf ksoap2 response

Tags: c#, java, android, wcf, dictionary

I have a wcf ksoap2 service that returns `Dictionary<ArrayList, List<byte[]>>`. Now at android side I want to fill my `Dictionary<String[], ArrayList<Object>> diction;` from wcf response. I am new to wcf and android/java, I don't have idea how to do this. Please provide me some better example of filling Dictionary with wcf.

Thanks in advance

This is my wcf code

```
public Dictionary<ArrayList, List<byte[]>> getImages()
        {
            Dictionary<ArrayList, List<byte[]>> image_Name = new Dictionary<ArrayList, List<byte[]>>();

            DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Yakhtar\Desktop\abc");
            arr1 = new ArrayList();
            foreach (FileInfo fi in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
                arr1.Add(fi.FullName);



            list = new List<byte[]>();
            for (int i = 0; i < arr1.Count; i++)
            {
                img = Image.FromFile(arr1[i].ToString());
                ms = new MemoryStream();
                img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                list.Add(ms.ToArray());
            }

            image_Name.Add(arr1, list);
            //image_Name[arr1 as ArrayList] = [list as byte[]];
            return image_Name;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this..

```
list = new List<byte[]>();
            for (int i = 0; i < arr1.Count; i++)
            {
                img = Image.FromFile(arr1[i].ToString());
                ms = new MemoryStream();
                img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                list.Add(ms.ToArray());
            }

            image_Name.Add(arr1, list);
            //image_Name[arr1 as ArrayList] = [list as byte[]];
            return image_Name;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Well I am not sure about that but have you thought about JSON parsing instead of ksoap2 ??

Here is a [tutorial on how to work with array of complex objects with KSOAP](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/2010/10/ksoap-android-web-service-tutorial-with.html). I found out by countless hours of debugging. Hope this hepls

also try this

```
SoapObject countryDetails = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
System.out.println(countryDetails.toString());

ArrayList list = new ArrayList(countryDetails.getPropertyCount());
lv_arr = new String[countryDetails.getPropertyCount()];
for (int i = 0; i < countryDetails.getPropertyCount(); i++) {
    Object property = countryDetails.getProperty(i);
    if (property instanceof SoapObject) {
        SoapObject countryObj = (SoapObject) property;
        String countryName = countryObj.getProperty("countryName").toString();
        list.add(countryName );
    }
}
```